# User/Account web service (.NET)

Tags: .net, sql, web-services

I want to build an web service in .NET that should handle basic user/account management. The initial interface should include (but might be extended in the future):

- CreateUser

  - Create a user with information such as Email, Name, Adress etc.
- UpdateUser

  - Update the user account information
- GetAssociatedData

  - Get data associated with this user

I could build this myself using by having the web service talk with the database, but I was wondering if there's any nice technology out there to manage accounts like this? There might even be something in .NET? If not, what should I consider when building it myself?

The users are arbitary users that doesn't belong to any windows domain or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SqlMembershipProvider` with `aspnet_regsql.exe` as a starting point and extends it to support custom data associated with the user.

Comment: Excellent. What's the best practice when using SqlMembershipProvider and ASP.NET Web Services when it comes to session handling? Some of the web methods requires a user to be logged in (authenticated).